# nginx reverse proxy to apache-wordpress works but proxy_pass to external url fails

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress, apache2

I have a nginx reverse proxy setup for apache wordpress which works fine. However based on location need to redirect to an external url which fails. Please check the below config. Is this a valid setup ?

- https://platform.com/ - this works - also any subsequent wp pages also works
- https://platform.com/pen - this needs to redirect to https://abcdef.com - this doesn't work - 404 page load error

Any help ?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;

    server_name platform.com;
    server_tokens off;

    root /var/www/html/def/public/;
    index index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /tmp/fgh.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /tmp/fgh.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access2.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error2.log;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            try_files $uri @apache;
    }

    location @apache {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

     location ~[^?]*/$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
     }

     location /pen {
            proxy_pass https://abcdef.com;
    }
   }
```

Comment: If you want to redirect not proxy then you need `return` not `proxy_pass` in the `/pen` location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the server name (wordpress site) from http prefix to www prefix, proxy pass re directions worked. Had to redirect all http https server blocks to www server block in nginx config